# php delete checkbox row with bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this bootstrap dropdown for set delete/publish/unpublish data in action form:

```
<div class="col-sm-7">
    <ul class="list-unstyled topControl">
        <li id="bulkAction">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Action <span class="caret"></span>

                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li data-action="3"><a href="#">Delete</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-action="1"><a href="#">Publish</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-action="0"><a href="#">Unpublish</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

in form I have this html:

```
<tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" class="itemCheckBox" value="6" />
        </td>
        <td>2323</td>
        <td>Project</td>
        <td>09-19-2014</td>
        <td> <a href="" class="label label-success">Published</a> 
        </td>
        <td> <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" href="" title="Edit post"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
 <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs confirmationDelete" href="" title="Delete post"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>

        </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" class="itemCheckBox" value="5" />
        </td>
        <td>2323</td>
        <td>Project</td>
        <td>09-19-2014</td>
        <td> <a href="" class="label label-success">Published</a> 
        </td>
        <td> <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" href="" title="Edit post"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
 <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs confirmationDelete" href="" title="Delete post"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>

        </td>
    </tr>
```

now I need to choose article in checkbox(one rows or multiple rows) than when click in dropdown menu (example delete) my form handle this and delete rows from database using PHP like this:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == "delete")
{
$selected = $_POST['id'];
if (count($_POST['id']) !== 0)
{
foreach($selected as $uid)
{
SQL::DELETE("DELETE FROM " . NEWS_ARTICLES . " WHERE id = ?", $uid);

}

echo "<div class=\"success\">" . $langmsg['editnews'][17] . "</div>";
}
}
```

how do can I create this?!

Answer (score 0):

You can add another field in the label `li` for example `data-selected="false"`
and when you clicked  on the `li` change the status `data-selected="true"`.

Then for retrieving the fields `$('li[data-selected=true]')`, and for get the values apply a `each` inside `$('li[data-selected=true]')`.